# Changing Startup Type In Windows

Tags: login, windows-services

I need to change the startup type for a Windows service to Automatic Delayed Start.

What I want to know is does this affect the 'log on as' at all?

For example if it is set to log on as another account and I change the setting will the service be affected in anyway such as stopping or failing to log on as the stated account the next time?

Answer (score 1):

> What I want to know is does this affect the 'log on as' at all?

No. The service will still start with the specified user.

> For example if it is set to log on as another account and I change the setting will the service be affected in anyway such as stopping or failing to log on as the stated account the next time?

Probably yes, but depends entirely on the way the service has been written. Such general questions can't be answered.

A service can stop working properly if you change the User Acc and/or if you change the startup type. Although most services will work fine even if set as delayed start if there is no other services depending on them.